# Vim Make and Run

Tags: vim, hotkeys

What would be the best way to make a hotkey that makes a project and then runs the generated binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nmap key :!make && ./a.out<CR>
```

This just runs `make` and, if it succeeds, runs `a.out`. If your binary is not named a.out, replace a.out with the name of the generated binary.